# Keyboard shortcuts Alt+a and Alt+r using javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, keydown

I want to show a `console.log()` using 2 shortcuts: `Alt+a` and `Alt+r` but it doesn't work and it don't shows me any message. That's the code

```
<script>
    $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
        if(e.which == 18 && e.which == 65) {
            console.log("ALT+A");
        } 
        if (e.which == 18 && e.which == 82) {
            console.log("ALT+R");
        }
    });
</script>
```

but, if i write:

```
<script>
    $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
        if(e.which == 18) {
            console.log("ALT");
        } 
    });
</script>
```

it works. I think that the problem is in the combination of the 2 keys but I'm not sure at all at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use altKey instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.altKey && e.which == 65) {
          console.log("ALT+A");
        }
        if (e.altKey && e.which == 82) {
          console.log("ALT+R");
        }
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/altKey

Comment: Thank you, it's working. Can I ask you why? I mean e.which == 18 it should be alt as well right?

Comment: @End.Game e.which can have only one value at a time. Hence, in your case, your conditions will never evaluate to true. Moreover, there are designated properties to check whether Ctrl, Shift, Alt are pressed.